# How do I convert a number into an 8-bit binary rather than 4-bit

Tags: c++

```cpp
void decimaltobin()
{
    binaryNum = 0;
    m = 1;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        rem = num % 2;
        num /= 2;
        binaryNum += rem * m;
        m *= 10;
    }
}
```

Just wondering if there was an easy fix to get this function to print an 8-bit binary number instead of a 4-bit number, e.g. `0000 0101` instead of `0101`.

Comment: Your function doesn't print anything.     In any event, your code needs to work out (without doing output) how may bits it would output.   If that number is `n`, output `8-n` leading zeros.   Then do the output of the `n` bits.

Comment: Is `binaryNum` a string or a number?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your code does not print anything yet and the data type of `binaryNum` is not clear. Here is a working solution.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void decToBinary(int n)
{
    // array to store binary number
    int binaryNum[32];
 
    // counter for binary array
    int i = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
 
        // storing remainder in binary array
        binaryNum[i] = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
        i++;
    }
    
    // printing the required number of zeros
    int zeros = 8 - i;
    for(int m = 0; m < zeros; m++){
        cout<<0;
    }
    // printing binary array in reverse order
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        cout << binaryNum[j];
}
 
// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    int n = 17;
    decToBinary(n);
    return 0;
}
```

The code implements the following:

- Store the remainder when the number is divided by 2 in an array.
- Divide the number by 2
- Repeat the above two steps until the number is greater than zero.
- Print the required number of zeros. That is 8 - length of the binary number. Note that this code will work for numbers that can be expressed in 8 bits only.
- Print the array in reverse order now
  [Ref](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-decimal-binary-conversion/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing your reason but why do you want to code from scratch instead of using a standard library?

You may use standard c++ without having to code a conversion from scratch using for instance [std::bitset<NB_OF_BITS>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Here is a simple example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

std::bitset<8> decimalToBin(int numberToConvert)
{
    return std::bitset<8>(numberToConvert);
}

int main() {
    int a = 4, b=8, c=12;
    std::cout << decimalToBin(a)<< std::endl;
    std::cout << decimalToBin(b)<< std::endl;
    std::cout << decimalToBin(c)<< std::endl;
}
```

It outputs:

```sh
00000100
00001000
00001100
```